# How to optmize query with subqueries,WHERE IN and varchar comparison fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, query-optimization

I am working on a scraping project to crawl items and their view counts over different schedules.Schedule is user defined period (date) when the script is intended to run.

Table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stats` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `schedule_id` smallint(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` smallint(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ;
```

All the data is stored in table stats and it will later analyzed to see the type wise growth in views.

The data would be like:

**Sample Set**

[image]

The scraping is done over periods and for each schedule it is expected to have about 20K entries.The schedules could be made in daily or weekly basis,hence the data would grow to be be around 2-3 million in 5-6 months.

Over this data I need to perform queries to aggregate the same name which come across the a selected range of schedules.

For example:

I need aggregate same items(name) which come across multiple schedules. If schedule 1 and 2 are selected,items which come under both of the schedules only will be selected.So here it would be **ItemA** and **ItemB**.

The type-wise sum of views should be calculated here.

Hence for schedule 1:**(UPDATED)**

```
SELECT COUNT(t.`type`) AS count, SUM(t.views) AS view_count 
FROM `stats` t 
INNER JOIN 
( 
   SELECT name,COUNT(name) as c FROM `stats` WHERE `schedule_id` IN (1,2) GROUP BY name HAVING c=2
) t2 ON t2.`name` = t.`name` 
WHERE `schedule_id`=2 GROUP BY type
```

[image]

**This is my expected result.**

But I have read using sub queries,WHERE IN, varchar comparison fields won't help in having an optimized query.How this could be optimized for better performance.

The rules for Same Type Aggregator would be as follows:

1.Under a schedule id, there could be same names with different type value.Combination of schedule_id,name and type won't be duplicated.

2.Type wise aggregator -which sums the values under each type is to be made.

I am doing the project in Python -MySQL for scraping purpose and PHP for listing results.I would like to know how to properly organize this table as well as query for better performance.
Please Advice.

Comment: For starters I'd make a dictionary table holding ids and corresponding names like `itemA` and store only ids in the main table. That would definitely speed up the query, and if you ever want to retrieve name you can always JOIN to the dict table by id.

Comment: @ConsiderMe names like ItemA is just a dummy value.In actual case it won't a smooth approach to take that into a dictionary table. If the varchar is creating problem,is it suggestible to convert the varchar names string into integer.

Comment: Not performance related but your sub query is trying to find records which have schedule_id of 1 and 2. However it will also match up any records which have schedule_id 1 twice. If this logically cannot happen then you might be able to rewrite it without a sub query easily.

Answer (score 1):

**VARCHAR COLUMN**

As said in the comment, it would be a good practice to store varchars in a dictionary table. Why? They require more space than for example int4 and thus having larger and larger table will only take more space, while each name can be stored once in another table.

**QUERY PERFORMANCE**

`WHERE IN` actually means that planner does compare `schedule_id` with `ANY'{1,2}'` converted to `integer[]` type which you can notice down below.

**SUBQUERIES**

You sometimes can not avoid subqueries, if you need to aggregate your data. Having this in mind, please remember that not all queries consist of 1 `SELECT` statement. In reality, they do very rarely (unless you have an application that only has it's tiny part connected with database, like for example simple game where you only need to store information containing users and points)

**QUERY**

Your query plan on given sample data:

```
select count(type), sum(views) from tmp_test8 a join (select name,count(1) from tmp_test8 where schedule_id in (1,2) group by 1 having count(1) = 2) b
on a.name = b.name where schedule_id = 1;

                                  QUERY PLAN                                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=23.59..23.60 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=11.77..23.59 rows=1 width=8)
         Join Filter: ((a.name)::text = (tmp_test8.name)::text)
         ->  Seq Scan on tmp_test8 a  (cost=0.00..11.75 rows=1 width=524)
               Filter: (schedule_id = 1)
         ->  HashAggregate  (cost=11.77..11.79 rows=2 width=516)
               Filter: (count(1) = 2)
               ->  Seq Scan on tmp_test8  (cost=0.00..11.75 rows=2 width=516)
                     Filter: (schedule_id = ANY ('{1,2}'::integer[]))
```

Though, your query could be rewritten without joins and thus it will only scan the table once. This is my suggestion:

```
select count, sum(view_count) 
from( 
    select name, count(1) count, sum(case when schedule_id = 1 then views end) view_count 
    from tmp_test8 
    where schedule_id in (1,2) 
    group by 1 
    having count(1) = 2 
    ) foo 
group by 1
                               QUERY PLAN                               
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=11.83..11.85 rows=2 width=16)
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=11.78..11.80 rows=2 width=524)
         Filter: (count(1) = 2)
         ->  Seq Scan on tmp_test8  (cost=0.00..11.75 rows=2 width=524)
               Filter: (schedule_id = ANY ('{1,2}'::integer[]))
```

Both queries would produce the same result.

Comment: Thanks for this. But in your second query there is a sub query with case check inside. I believe it would fetch slower slower with a larger data set.

Comment: @Surabhil excuse me, but every query provided with larger data set will fetch slower and slower. That's pretty obvious. You could run a testcase, but the query plan will ALWAYS* (unless you change something outside the query like indexes) stay the same, no matter how many rows your data sample will contain.

Comment: Yes sure,I could understand things with larger data.But I think we should take care of all the basic optimizations from our part.

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comment.

If a name can have duplicate schedule ids then your current query will not work. The simplest fix would be to change it from *COUNT(name)* to *COUNT(DISTINCT schedule_id)* .

If for a name then schedule_id is unique then you could avoid the sub query by joining against stats once for each schedule id:-

```
SELECT COUNT(t.`type`) AS count, SUM(t.views) AS view_count 
FROM `stats` t 
INNER JOIN stats t1 ON t.name = t1.name AND t1.schedule_id = 1
INNER JOIN stats t2 ON t.name = t2.name AND t2.schedule_id = 2
WHERE t.schedule_id = 1
```

This is making a few assumptions about your data.

While sub queries are necessary sometimes, MySQL does not use an index on the result of the sub query to join it with the main table.

Comment: I'd assume name won't have a duplicate entry with the same `schedule_id`. You can see by the schema, that `views` do get updated and `updated_time` does get changed whenever it's done.

Comment: @ConsiderMe - that would be my hope but not certain. If name can't have duplicate entries for the same schedule_id then it makes it easy to avoid the sub query (at which point an index covering name and schedule_id would likely greatly help - or better as you suggest split the name off and use its id for the join)

Comment: @Kickstart I have updated the question.
on changing //COUNT(name) to COUNT(DISTINCT schedule_id)//
Is using **DISTINCT** under **COUNT** a good practice? And in my case there could be multiple name field with different types under a single schedule.

Comment: COUNT(name) and COUNT(DISTINCT name) do 2 different things and are not interchangeable.  If required use DISTINCT. In your case can you have the same name multiple times with the SAME schedule?